# The notion of border for (complex and non-archimedean) analytic spaces and schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, shimura-varieties, analytic-geometry, gaga

Is a manifold with corner an analytic space (just show that $\left[0, +\infty \right)^{n}$ is an analytic space, which seems obvious but maybe I'm wrong...) EDIT: as noted in the comments some complex manifolds with corner can't be analytic spaces because they have to low codimension of singularity locus so I'm now asking **which manifolds with corner are analytic spaces?**.

**Question 1** Am I right? And if so, how do you characterize the corner of an analytic space with its sheaf of holomorphic functions?

**Question 2** What then is the corner of a scheme? Is the analytification of the corner the corner of the analytification?

**Question 3** Same question but for the non-Archimedean analytic space (rigid-analytic, perfectoid, etc.). I'm a real noob in non-archimedean geometry, hope my question makes sense.

**Question 4** Same question for stack.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "analytic space"? Usually those are required to be manifolds, more or less by definition, so $[0,\infty)^n$ won't be one.

Comment: @Wojowu analytic spaces are, for me, generalisation of manifold which allows singular points. We can see them (up to a topological detail) as we see algebraic varieties but instead of affine varieties being quotient of polynomial ring by polynomials we take affine variety being quotient of holomorphic function ring by some holomorphic functions.

Comment: So what is the exact *definition* of an "analytic space" for you?

Comment: @Wojowu I just tell you actually.. See e.g. the wiki web page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_space#:~:text=An%20analytic%20space%20is%20a%20locally%20ringed%20space%20such%20that,model%20for%20X%20at%20x.

Comment: In that case the answer is trivially no - you haven't specified the structure sheaf. It would be more reasonable to ask whether these topological spaces admit an analytic space structure - in this case, the answer is no. This is because the singular locus of an analytic space must have real codimension at least $2$, but the entire boundary of $[0,\infty)^n$ must be contained in singular locus, and it has codimension $1$.

Comment: @Wojowu there is a notion of holomorphic functions on a manifold with border, the structure sheaf I had in mind was that sheaf. I should have say that. 
I intuitively belive in your fact that singular locus has codimension 2. But how to prove it? 
Also I can cheat a bit just by asking for manifold with border with singular locus of codimension at least 2 (and then changing $\left[0,\infty\right)^{n}$ in my question by $\left[0,\infty\right)^{n-2}\times \mathbb{C}$). And finaly what could be an analytic space with border?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139876/discussion-between-marsault-chabat-and-wojowu).

Comment: What is a manifold with "border"? Do you mean a manifold with corner?

Comment: A formal definition is necessary to see what kind of boundaries would you incorporate, i.e. what sort of local models do you consider. The boundary of an embedded open manifold might be extremely singular in general. Think of a continuous but not differentiable simple curve (e.g. nowhere differentiable curves appearing in fractal geometry) $S^1\to\mathbb C$, which encircles a region with boundary with no smoothness at all.